# Liberar consulta y cerrar conexión a la base de datos

Tags: php, sql

He escrito este código para guardar datos de un formulario en la base de datos, pero al finalizar la conexión me da error (en el código se ve lo que puse comentado). A continuación muestro el mensaje de error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Las líneas 46 y 47 son:

```
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysql_close($conexion);
```

Además, hay veces que no me guarda nada en la base de datos y no sé si será a causa de esto o que hay algún error más.

Código PHP:

```
<?php
// Recojo los datos del formulario
$campo1 = $_POST['Campo1'];
$campo2 = $_POST['Campo2'];
$campo3 = $_POST['Campo3'];

// La variable revisión la emplearemos a modo de booleano, si es 1 es que la propuesta está pendiente de revision.
$revision = 1;

// Conectamos con la base de datos.
// LOCAL
$bd_host = "localhost"; 
$bd_usuario = "root"; 
$bd_password = ""; 
$bd_base = "carrot";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($bd_host, $bd_usuario, $bd_password); 
mysqli_select_db($conexion,$bd_base);

// Hacemos la consulta. En este caso queremos guardar los valores del formulario en la bd
$consulta = "
    INSERT INTO propuesta(campo1, campo2, campo3, revision)
    VALUES ($campo1, $campo2, $campo3, $revision)
";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

// Liberamos y cerramos conexión.
/*mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysql_close($conexion);*/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por un lado [`mysqli_free_result()`](http://php.net/mysqli_free_result) se usa para liberar un resultado y parece que lo que tienes en `$resultado` es un valor booleano debido a que falló la consulta. Por otro lado estás confundiendo las funciones `mysqli_*` con las `mysql_*`. Deberías hacer uso de [`mysqli_close()`](http://php.net/mysqli_close) en lugar de [`mysql_close()`](http://php.net/mysql_close).

Además: **NO DEBES CONCATENAR CADENAS** para generar un SQL, en su lugar debes usar consultas preparadas para que la consulta no falle en caso de contener una comilla simple (`'`) o un valor vacío (un campo `VALUES` vacío es un error sintáctico) ni sufras de [un problema grave de seguridad](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpKIhF7naSY) llamado [inyección SQL](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inyecci%C3%B3n_SQL).

Al menos, si no deseas usar consultas preparadas, deberías escapar correctamente las cadenas haciendo uso de [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/mysqli_real_escape_string).

Gestionando correctamente los errores (mediante la comprobación del valor de `$resultado` tras la llamada a `mysqli_query()` podrás averiguar el motivo por el que falla la consulta y los valores no son insertados en la base de datos.

Una forma de hacer todo lo que te propongo sería de la siguiente manera:

```
<?php
// La variable revisión la emplearemos a modo de booleano, si es 1 es que la propuesta está pendiente de revision.
$revision = 1;

// Conectamos con la base de datos.
// LOCAL
$bd_host = "localhost"; 
$bd_usuario = "root"; 
$bd_password = ""; 
$bd_base = "carrot";

$conexion = mysqli_connect($bd_host, $bd_usuario, $bd_password); 
mysqli_select_db($conexion,$bd_base);

// Recojo los datos del formulario
/* NOTAR EL USO DE LA FUNCIÓN DE ESCAPADO */
$campo1 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['Campo1']);
$campo2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['Campo2']);
$campo3 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conexion, $_POST['Campo3']);

// Hacemos la consulta. En este caso queremos guardar los valores del formulario en la bd
/* NOTAR EL USO DE COMILLAS PARA DELIMITAR VALORES VACÍOS */
$consulta = "
    INSERT INTO propuesta(campo1, campo2, campo3, revision)
    VALUES ('$campo1', '$campo2', '$campo3', '$revision')
";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);
/* NOTAR EL CONTROL DE ERROR */
if ($resultado === false) {
  die("Error SQL: ", mysqli_error($conexion));
}

// Liberamos y cerramos conexión.
mysqli_free_result($resultado);
mysqli_close($conexion);
```